# How to use a form instead of a link for AngularJS Single Page App to go to different pages?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS's Single Page App using ngRoute, we can jump to different pages using:

```
<a href="#/secondPage" class="btn btn-primary">Get Data</a>
```

However, there is a text input box above (`<input type="text" ng-model="someTextInput">`, and it won't respond to the Enter key this way (they are not inside of a `<form>` element.  So the user has to type something into the text box, and click on the link below, which looks like a button due to Bootstrap's CSS styling.

The question is:

1. How would we make pressing Enter work? (maybe adding something that is part of AngularJS)
2. What if I just change the HTML to a form with a submit button:

   ```
   <form class="form-group" method="get" action="#/secondPage">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="someTextInput">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Data</button>
   </form>
   ```

Is this the AngularJS way of doing it?  Is it actually exactly the same as using a `<a href="#/  ">` to do it but just having Enter respond to the user?

(It feels slower or I wonder if it is just my imagination (maybe by pressing Enter I expected it to respond immediately than if I actually go to the mouse and click, then it is already 1 second there and so I don't mind the 0.5 second of going to the second page afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly:

- User enter something in the input
- Press Enter
- Should navigate to second page

Then following code should work:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="someTextInput" ng-keyup="handleKeyUp($event)">
```

Then in your controller (js file) if you are using $scope syntax :

```
module.controller('yourController', function ($scope, ..., $location))

  ...

 $scope.handleKeyUp = function ($event) {
      if ($event.keyCode === 13) {
           $location.path('/secondPage');
       }
 }
```

Comment: is using a form also a standard way to do it in AngularJS?

Comment: Form are used to collect and post data, for example if you have multiple inputs, checkbox and so on, and have Next button at the bottom on which you can call function via `ng-click` from the scope where you can navigate to second page., you can use Enter to navigate to next page (just move ng-keyup to form, so it will catch Enter in any of the inputs). 

But using form and **action** attribute is not the correct way. Add ng-click on the button and call function from the scope that will navigate to the next page.

Comment: i suppose that can make sense, but just that if looking into a keypress event, then it looks quite low level handling. Maybe if made into a directive then can be more abstract level

Comment: Well yes, directive is always a good idea if you plan to reuse same functionality later on to some other form, or to hide some low level logic (in our case keypress event). 
You can make directive that can handle keypress event on the given element and execute some passed function when event is triggered. Then just add directive to the form : `<form ....  on-enter-pressed="doSomething()" >`

Comment: oh, I also just saw one way, which is `ngSubmit`, essentially, it is `<form ng-submit="submit()">` and in the controller, define `$scope.submit = function() { ... }` and use `$location` like you do